# Chromedriver working in path but not with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been attempting to use the selenium webdriver with Google Chrome.
I have installed chromedriver, and set the path to it. This has been done correctly as when I run chromedriver in terminal I get the output

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552518 
on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed
```

However, when I attempt to use the chromedriver on my python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get this following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'
```

I've tried multiple methods of specifying the direct path and also putting the chromedriver file in the folder the python script is in. But nothing seems to be working and they all give the same error!

Please Help!

edit:

Path has been set in bash profile as such:

```
export PATH="~/drivers/:${PATH}"
```

Attempted Path specified in the python script as such:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("~/drivers/chromedriver")
```

Still with the same error of:

```
No such file or directory: '~/drivers/chromedriver': '~/drivers/chromedriver'
```

Comment: I think you are not setting your path right. Try using `export PATH=$PATH:/place/with/the/file` without the curly braces and the quotes

Comment: Java can't understand `~` is user home folder,  only Linux Shell know it represents user home folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java can't understand  `~/drivers/chromedriver`, Because only Linux Shell understand  `~` is user home folder, But Java can't.

So your should use absolute path like `/home/<userA>/drivers/chromedriver` or relative path like `../drivers/chromedriver`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Path :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Unfortunatey, i've tried and get the same sort of error:

     No such file or directory: '~/drivers/chromedriver': '~/drivers/chromedriver'

Comment: how you are giving the path . share your code please

Comment: this is my script :  from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com")   and it is working on my machine

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.5 on windows 10 and chrom-driver version is 2.38 and chrome version is 66

Comment: there is something wrong with your path check once !

Answer (score 0):

download selenium **server-standalone**-3.12.0.jar

and  try this in a terminal:
`export CLASSPATH=".:selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar`"